# How to remove double quotes when loading csv into external table in impala?

Tags: csv, impala

This is the data (you can also download it from [here](https://www.toronto.ca/city-government/data-research-maps/open-data/open-data-catalogue/#2fc027de-d27a-2a00-1388-6849497cb84c)):

```
"Creation Date","Status","First 3 Chars of Postal Code","Intersection Street 1","Intersection Street 2","Ward","Service Request Type","Division","Section"
"2010-01-01 00:38:26.0000000","Closed","Intersection","High Park Blvd","Parkside Dr","Parkdale-High Park (13)","Road - Sanding / Salting Required","Transportation Services","Road Operations"
"2010-01-01 01:19:18.0000000","Closed","M4T","","","Toronto Centre-Rosedale (27)","Water Service Line-Turn On","Toronto Water","District Ops"
```

This is my create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE sr.sr2013 ( 
creation_date STRING,   
status STRING,   
first_3_chars_of_postal_code STRING,   
intersection_street_1 STRING,   
intersection_street_2 STRING,   
ward STRING,   
service_request_type STRING,   
division STRING,   
section STRING ) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'colelction.delim'='\u0002', 
'mapkey.delim'='\u0003', 
'serialization.format'=',', 
'field.delim'=',', 
'skip.header.line.count'='1',
'quoteChar'= "\"") ;
```

This is the load data query:

```
load data inpath '/user/rxie/SR2013.csv' into table sr2013;
```

After data is loaded, checking the table found all the original quotes are retained:

[image]

So at least two issues here:
1. the header is not excluded by the option `'skip.header.line.count'='1',` in the table creation;
2. the double quotes are not removed as indicated by the option `'quoteChar'= "\""` when loading data into the table

Can anyone share with more light? it looks like bugs to me.

UPDATE 1:

In Hue/Hive editor:

```
creation_date STRING,   
status STRING,   
first_3_chars_of_postal_code STRING,   
intersection_street_1 STRING,   
intersection_street_2 STRING,   
ward STRING,   
service_request_type STRING,   
division STRING,   
section STRING )                               
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (                             
   'colelction.delim'='\u0002',                     
   'field.delim'=',',                               
   'mapkey.delim'='\u0003',                         
   'serialization.format'=',',
   'skip.header.line.count'='1',   
   'quoteChar'= "\"") 


   LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/rxie/data/csv/SR2015.csv' INTO TABLE sr2015;
```

Error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 1:26
>   Invalid path ''/home/rxie/data/csv/SR2015.csv'': No files matching
>   path file:/home/rxie/data/csv/SR2015.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what works for me to load csv with quotes be excluded is as below:

In Hive Editor (I assume beeline is good too though I didn't test it out):

1. Create Hive table

   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sr2015(
   creation_date STRING,
   status STRING,
   first_3_chars_of_postal_code STRING,
   intersection_street_1 STRING,
   intersection_street_2 STRING,
   ward STRING,
   service_request_type STRING,
   division STRING,
   section STRING )
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
      'colelction.delim'='\u0002',
      'field.delim'=',',
      'mapkey.delim'='\u0003',
      'serialization.format'=',',
      'skip.header.line.count'='1',
      'quoteChar'= "\"")
2. Load data into Hive table:

   LOAD DATA  INPATH    "hdfs:///user/rxie/SR2015.csv" INTO TABLE sr2015;

Pending issue(will be discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586148/how-to-load-data-to-hive-table-and-make-it-also-accessible-in-impala)):
The table is not accessible in Impala